# Nestjs typeorm returns empty array when trying to filter entities by date

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I am trying to filter events by date, i thought this was an issue of input from frontend, but a hardcoded date doesn't return anything either. The response is:

```
count: 1 // so it knows that there is something that fits the where clause
result: []
```

This is the service code:

```
async findAllByDate(
    min: string | undefined,
    max: string | undefined,
    skip: number,
  ) {
    const [result, total] = await this.repository.findAndCount({
      take: 10,
      skip: skip,
      where: {
        date: MoreThanOrEqual('2022-06-20'),
      },
    });

    console.log(result);

    return {
      data: result,
      count: total,
    };
  }
```

Comment: What is the value of `skip`? Is it possible the count query is counting everything without skipping anything?

Comment: Value of skip is 0